# importing a class and an object of different class using the method of the class

Tags: python, import

Hi I am a beginner to python. 
The question I have is this. When you import a class, then can you use the method attribute of the class to an instance of different class? 
Like an attribute(like get_value()) that belongs to class A is used to an instance of class B. Like 
b.get_value()

The question that I am stuck is below. I am learning a stack. The question I have is, according to what I have learned up until now, the constructor should be as this

```
def __init__(self, value=None):
  self.top_item = Node(value)
def peek(self):
  return self.top_item,get_value()
```

But below self.top_item is set to none, yet still uses method attribute of Node. This is what throws me off.

```
from node import Node

# Add your Stack class below:
class Stack:
  def __init__(self):
    self.top_item = None
  def peek(self):
    return self.top_item.get_value()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. If you want to get the value from class B , you need to have a class method of Class B. You cannot use class method of class A on class B. But you can create a similar method for class B and then you can create an instance of B and then call it.